# How to handle hybrid communication with HTTP and WebSockets?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, real-time

I am developing application in NestJS and React where user can create admin account and later create room. To the room can join everyone with frontend link, guests have to choose their name from list (defined by admin). After that admin can start voting session, and guests can choose vote which will be visible to everyone in the room.

My question is if is better to handle vote (and other actions that will cause real-time update for everyone) with HTTP POST which in handler will emit websocket message about update for all participants, or all communication like that should be done with websockets messages to sever?

I am not sure about pros and cons of both approaches. I am dealing first time with websockets. Thanks for help